# Sync Kubernetes Storage with files from Windows

Tags: storage, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

We want to **migrate** some applications **to google kubernetes**. One of these applications is strictly **bound to a folder**, from which it reads files, which are exported from a third-party application. My dewy-eyed idea from an easy windows-mount or similar was destroyed at a great pace. My second idea with a **google bucket, rclone and fuse** is "okay" but not optimal for lots of small files.

We have a **VPN** in kubernetes, with which we are able to **connect to our widows-servers**.

So my question is:

1. what is the best option to **read** files **from a windows host** out of a **pod**?
2. what is the best option to **copy** files **from** our legacy **windows hosts** to a **storage**, which can be **mounted** to a **pod**?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is possible using default GCE/GKE resources/options, I think that you want to check [FS on GCE](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/filers-on-compute-engine#filer_options) but using the filer option since per what you are explaining a PD isn't going to be helpful. About best option for cp, I found this [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices#uploading) for Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to SMB mount a windows machine, but we don't have a built0-in volume driver for SMB.

You would do better to upload to GCS and sync to your pods (or FUSE, I guess) or to upload your data to git and sync down to pods with a git-sync sidecar.  This has the nice property that you can pin versions, roll back, etc.